# Rails foursquare2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, architecture, foursquare

Hi i have a post model and post model has many places. I join them with a table called post_places.

In my new Post form i show the user the closest places via [foursquare](https://github.com/mattmueller/foursquare2) and allow multiple places to be selected.I have no problems so far.

The code I show for nearby locations:

```
<div class="field">
      <%= f.label :place_ids, 'Places' %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select :place_ids, @places['venues'], :id, :name, {:prompt => "Select a place"}, {class: 'form-control', :multiple => true} %>
</div>
```

Here is a image from my new post form (results from foursquare api):[image]

If I use before action, @post throws an error that is not found, and if I use an after action, it throws an error because place_ids is foursquare.Here is the code:

```
  post_params[:place_ids].drop(1).each do |place|
        venue = foursquare.venue(place)
        @post.places.new(title: venue['name'], address: venue['location']['address'], latitude: venue['location']['lat'], longitude: venue['location']['lng'])
  end
```

I can get the address, longitude and latitude information of the selected places and it is exactly what they are in the places table fields.

1-)How do I track the places that the user selects here and then save them to the post_places table?

2-)How do I make it not to re-register if the place is already registered in the places table?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a form and pass the values of the selection in a post request saving them to a database.
2. Validate uniqueness of the place relative to the user_id

Comment: I can not do this because the places I've shown in the form are not ActiveRecord models.Do I need to register it as places, primarily with the foursquare place id from the form?